# How can you get the parent of a UIElement?

Tags: wpf, panel, parent, children, uielement

Ok, I know that `FrameworkElement`, which is a direct subclass of `UIElement`, has a `Parent` property, but `Panel` objects have children of type `UIElement`, not `FrameworkElement` (The `Children` property is of type `UIElementCollection`) which seems it would mean you can add `UIElement`s directly to a `Panel`.

That said, if you have a `UIElement` and want to see if it has a parent that's a panel, the only way I know how to test this is with the `VisualTreeHelper`, but that's the visual tree, not the logical tree.  (At least we know a panel doesn't have a template so maybe that's the way, but still...)

So asides from the `VisualTreeHelper`, how can you determine which panel (if any) is the parent of a `UIElement`? (...and have any thoughts why they didn't just define a Parent property there instead of on `FrameworkElement`?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you need to find a logical parent you can just use `LogicalTreeHelper` in the same manner as `VisualTreeHelper`.

As for "...and have any thoughts why they didn't just define a Parent property there instead of on `FrameworkElement`?". Basically, the notion of "Logical Tree" is introduced on the `FrameworkElement` level. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx (see Remarks) for details of what `FrameworkElement` adds to `UIElement`. Here is what it says about Logical Trees:

> **The logical tree:** The general WPF
>   programming model is often expressed
>   in terms of being a tree of elements.
>   Support for expressing the tree of
>   elements as a logical tree, and
>   accompanying support for defining that
>   tree in markup is implemented at the
>   FrameworkElement level. Note however
>   that FrameworkElement deliberately
>   does not define a content model, and
>   leaves that responsibility to derived
>   classes. For more information, see
>   [Trees in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx).

Comment: I know the diff. between the physical tree and the logical tree.  That's not what I asked.  Nor can I use the LogicalTreeHelper here as the canvas may very well be part of the Visual Tree.  I do however see your point about the parent.  My argument there would be why not create separate VisualParent too then?  Guess what it comes down to is I have no choice but to use the VisualTreeHelper (and maybe an attached method for convenience) to get the parent panel.  And even though technically it's not the answer, I'm marking it as such anyway because it doesn't look like there is one.