# Close WPF User Control Popup in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am showing User Control as Dialog in WPF-MVVM application. Here is the code.

```
  var ProductView = new Product();
  var ProductViewModel = new ProductViewModel();
  ProductView.DataContext = ProductViewModel;
  this.ShowDialogWindow("Add Product", ProductView);
```

and this ShowDialogWindow Method is like this

```
 protected void ShowDialogWindow(string header, UserControl control)
 {
        RadWindow window = new RadWindow();
        window.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;
        window.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        window.Content = control;          
        window.Header = header;
        window.CanClose = true;
        window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        window.ShowDialog();
 }
```

Now, I have a button "Close" in the DialogWindow User Control. How can I close window using that button ?

NOTE: This is a WPF User Control not Window. I want to close using MVVM only

Comment: You say it's not a window, but the ShowDialog creates and shows a window.  Are you trying to have a view model close a view?  If so I suggest using a mediator pattern to send and subscribe to messages, something like is discussed here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35277/MVVM-Mediator-Pattern

Comment: @PaulGibson Window that is showing is also a User Control

Answer (score 1):

Consider leveraging messaging with parameters to pass around data between your objects.

You can use an [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) or [MessageBus](https://bizmonger.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/decoupled-event-management/).

You can pull in the MessageBus from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bizmonger.Patterns).

You can then do a subscribe and publish using MessageBus.Instance.

The idea is to have your user controls subscribe to events that they would like to respond to.

NOTE:

I do this with viewmodels.
However, I think it is a code-smell when adding this code to user-controls that are meant to have general use regardless of the application employing them.

I use the ***Publish Subscribe pattern*** for complicated class-dependencies:

**ViewModel:**

```
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            CloseComand = new DelegateCommand((obj) =>
                {
                    MessageBus.Instance.Publish(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, null);
                });
        }
}
```

**Window:**

```
public partial class SomeWindow : Window
{
    Subscription _subscription = new Subscription();

    public SomeWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _subscription.Subscribe(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, obj =>
            {
                this.Close();
            });
    }
}
```

You can leverage [Bizmonger.Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) to get the MessageBus.

**MessageBus**

```
public class MessageBus
{
    #region Singleton
    static MessageBus _messageBus = null;
    private MessageBus() { }

    public static MessageBus Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_messageBus == null)
            {
                _messageBus = new MessageBus();
            }

            return _messageBus;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Members
    List<Observer> _observers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _oneTimeObservers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _waitingSubscribers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _waitingUnsubscribers = new List<Observer>();

    int _publishingCount = 0;
    #endregion

    public void Subscribe(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        Subscribe(message, response, _observers);
    }

    public void SubscribeFirstPublication(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        Subscribe(message, response, _oneTimeObservers);
    }

    public int Unsubscribe(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Respond == response).ToList());
        observers.AddRange(_waitingSubscribers.Where(o => o.Respond == response));
        observers.AddRange(_oneTimeObservers.Where(o => o.Respond == response));

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.ForEach(o => _observers.Remove(o));
        }

        else
        {
            _waitingUnsubscribers.AddRange(observers);
        }

        return observers.Count;
    }

    public int Unsubscribe(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription).ToList());
        observers.AddRange(_waitingSubscribers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));
        observers.AddRange(_oneTimeObservers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.ForEach(o => _observers.Remove(o));
        }

        else
        {
            _waitingUnsubscribers.AddRange(observers);
        }

        return observers.Count;
    }

    public void Publish(string message, object payload)
    {
        _publishingCount++;

        Publish(_observers, message, payload);
        Publish(_oneTimeObservers, message, payload);
        Publish(_waitingSubscribers, message, payload);

        _oneTimeObservers.RemoveAll(o => o.Subscription == message);
        _waitingUnsubscribers.Clear();

        _publishingCount--;
    }

    private void Publish(List<Observer> observers, string message, object payload)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_publishingCount >= 0);

        var subscribers = observers.Where(o => o.Subscription.ToLower() == message.ToLower());

        foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
        {
            subscriber.Respond(payload);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Observer> GetObservers(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));
        return observers;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _observers.Clear();
        _oneTimeObservers.Clear();
    }

    #region Helpers
    private void Subscribe(string message, Action<object> response, List<Observer> observers)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_publishingCount >= 0);

        var observer = new Observer() { Subscription = message, Respond = response };

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.Add(observer);
        }
        else
        {
            _waitingSubscribers.Add(observer);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

**Subscription**

```
public class Subscription
{
    #region Members
    List<Observer> _observerList = new List<Observer>();
    #endregion

    public void Unsubscribe(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = _observerList.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription);

        foreach (var observer in observers)
        {
            MessageBus.Instance.Unsubscribe(observer.Subscription, observer.Respond);
        }

        _observerList.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription).ToList().ForEach(o => _observerList.Remove(o));
    }

    public void Subscribe(string subscription, Action<object> response)
    {
        MessageBus.Instance.Subscribe(subscription, response);
        _observerList.Add(new Observer() { Subscription = subscription, Respond = response });
    }

    public void SubscribeFirstPublication(string subscription, Action<object> response)
    {
        MessageBus.Instance.SubscribeFirstPublication(subscription, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are talking about window. I clearly mention that I am using User Control. For Window, I can see this.close() but for User Control, there is Close() method

Comment: Dialogs are "clearly" windows regardless of their content. A window is the control that you have the ability to close.

Comment: I understand that but  for the following code. there is no this.close() for user control. _subscription.Subscribe(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, obj =>
            {
                this.Close();
            });

Comment: Yes, because your usercontrol is contained within a Window element. So rely on your window instance to handle the close. Get your parent control until it is a window type and do it there.

Comment: How can I get window instance of the user control ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000228/how-can-you-get-the-parent-of-a-uielement and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type

Comment: in the window constructor code simply subscribe to the window close message and have the window close itself.