# How to Find UserControl Parent?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I want to find the parent of usercontrol from Markup,
I used the following code

```
var hostRoot = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider)) as IRootObjectProvider;
var host = hostRoot.RootObject;

var do = host as DependencyObject;
var uc = do as UserControl;
var ucParent = uc.Parent;
```

and

```
var wp = Window.GetWindow(uc);
```

But both return null

Update:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp12.MainWindow">
    <Grid>
       <local:UserControl1/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp12.UserControl1">
    <StackPanel>
       
        <TextBlock Text="{me:myMarkup}"/>

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Update 2:

this is my Markup

```
public class myMarkup : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var hostRoot = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider)) as IRootObjectProvider;
            var host = hostRoot.RootObject;
            var xv = host as DependencyObject;

            var ww = Window.GetWindow(xv);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Update 3:
sample project

https://github.com/ghost1372/HandyControls/files/6259944/WpfApp18.zip

Comment: I wouldn't use `do` as variable name as this is a C# keyword. On to the question, what is your `uc` set to? Because if the parent is null then it suggests the user control hasn't been added to the element tree.

Comment: Forget naming This is just an example, Usercontrol is inside Window

Comment: In that case could you provide a minimum reproducible example? Because if the user control has been added to the logical tree then the parent should be set.

Comment: @ekke i updated my question Is it enough or do I have to upload a project?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000228/how-can-you-get-the-parent-of-a-uielement ?

Comment: I don't think there's anything obviously wrong with your code that I can see. Uploading a sample project would probably help.

Comment: @ekke i uploaded a sample project

Comment: @Serg no not work

Comment: Hey so it looks like you're trying to access the logical tree before `InitializeComponent` has completed. `InitializeComponent` builds the logical tree up including initialising the parent from the XAML. You won't be able to access this like this. If you can explain what you're trying to do, perhaps it's possible to achieve it another way?

Comment: My markup is a bit complicated and i wrote it for localization, Provider property is registered in Windows, so I need to have access to Windows to be able to read Provider

Comment: @ekke i used Application.Current.MainWindow Not too good, but not too bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until the `UserControl` has been loaded before calling `Window.GetWindow`:

```
public class myMarkup : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var hostRoot = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider)) as IRootObjectProvider;
        var host = hostRoot.RootObject;
        var xv = host as FrameworkElement;

        //local function:
        void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement xv = (FrameworkElement)sender;
            Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(xv);
            //do something with the window...
        }

        Window parentWindow;
        if (xv.IsLoaded)
        {
            parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(xv);
            //do something with the window...
        }
        else
        {
            xv.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```